# Remove the timestamp part in a timestamp with timezone field

Tags: java, postgresql, sql-timestamp

I need to update a Java `LocalDateTime` field to a Postgres table in which the field is a timestamp with time zone,  but the catch is i've to set the time field to 00:00:00+00 and keep the date field as it is.

I've modified the field in java like this

```
dateToBeSet.withNano(00).withSecond(00).withMinute(00).withHour(00)
```

but when the data is getting inserted to the database, in the log i could see that the data getting inserted as `2019-01-23 00:00:00+05:30`.
How can I get rid of this `+5:30` and just insert the data as it is getting provided from the java side?

The expected value in the DB is **`2019-01-23 00:00:00+00`**

Comment: You seem to be confused as to the nature of the `LocalDateTime` class. That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, it *cannot* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. It represents *potential* moments along a range of 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe. That class is appropriate for values retrieved from Postgres in a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. For the `WITH TIME ZONE` type you should be using `OffsetDateTime` class, as that column type and that class both represent a moment, a point on the timeline,

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for the clarification, but in my case i cannot change the type in java or in the database. It is an already running application, this is kind of a special situation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get rid of the time zone in the database, because it is not stored there.

Internally, what is stored is a UTC timestamp, and when it is converted to a string, it is transformed to the time zone indicated by the `timezone` parameter.

So if you want the timestamp to be the same, regardless of the current setting of `timezone`, you need to use the `timestamp without time zone` data type.

As an alternative, retrieve the value using the construct

```
ts_field AT TIME ZONE 'IST'
```

using a time zone name in which you want the timestamp to be rendered.